# Get pointer to raw data in set like &(vector[0])

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, set, containers

To get the pointer to the data in a vector we can use

```
vector<double> Vec;    
double* Array_Pointer = &(Vec[0]);
Function(Array_Pointer);
```

Is that possible to get the pointer to the data in a **set**? Can I use that as array pointer like above?

---

If not possible, what is the best way to make a vector out of set? I mean without loop over all elements.

Comment: In a vector, that data is contiguous. How would this work in a set?

Comment: The data container should be contiguous in set too! Why not? I don't mean the order of elements but storage of elements. otherwise it couldn't be efficient

Comment: Not likely. It's not guaranteed to be contiguous by the standard, and making it contiguous would probably upset some complexity requirements.

Comment: Because one of the guarantees of set is that inserting, erasing and searching operations all have complexity O(log(n)).  If the data was contiguous, it would be very difficult to keep that promise.

Comment: You might be able to use `std::priority_queue` instead of `std::set`; this structure may have contiguous storage and is partially, but not completely, sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily possible.  The C++ ISO standard explicitly guarantees contiguous storage of elements in a `std::vector`, so you can safely take the address of the first element and then use that pointer as if you were pointing at a raw array.  Other containers in the standard library do not have this guarantee.

The reason for this is to efficiently support most operations on a `std::set`, the implementation needs to use complex data structures like balanced binary search trees to store and organize the data.  These structures are inherently nonlinear and require nodes to be allocated and linked together.  Efficiently getting this to work with the elements in a flat array would be difficult, if not impossible, in the time constraints laid out by the standard (amortized O(log n) for most operations.)

**EDIT**: In response to your question - there is no way to build a `std::vector` from a `std::set` without some code somewhere iterating over the set and copying the elements over.  You can do this without explicitly using any loops yourself by using the `std::vector` range constructor:

```
std::vector<T> vec(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, what is the best way to make a vector out of set?

Comment: Does it also work with map: vec(myMap.begin(), myMap.end()); ?

Comment: @Hesam- Since maps store key/value pairs, this will only work if the vector stores key/value pairs.  There is no direct way to get just the keys or values this way; you'd need to use an explicit loop.

Comment: @chris- Yes, but then you'd need to define a function (or lambda) to take just the first or second element of the pair.  Perhaps I was too strong in my initial assertion.

Comment: @templatetypedef, Well, it isn't that much of a bother :p `[](decltype(myMap)::value_type &p) {return p.first;}`

Comment: @chris- Methinks that the normal for loop might be a bit easier to read. :-)  But yes, that should work!

Comment: @templatetypedef, Just wait until we get polymorphic lambdas!

Comment: Is there any efficiency difference if I use vec(mySet.begin(), mySet.end()) versus iterating over elements?

Comment: @Hesam: Probably not.  But you may experience some gains with the following: `vector<double> v; v.reserve(mySet.size()); v.assign(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());`

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible to implement `set` in such a way that you can do this.

If you implement `set` in such a way that elements are stored in a single array, then when you add more elements, that array will inevitably need to be reallocated at some point. At that time, any references to existing elements will be invalidated.

One of features of `set` is that it *guarantees* that references to elements will never be invalidated if you add (or remove) other elements. As stated in [associative.reqmts]:

> The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

So it's *impossible* to implement `set` in such a way that all of the elements of the set are stored in a single array.

Note that this has nothing to do with the efficiency requirements such as O(log n) insert/delete/lookup (if you squint really hard and allow for amortized O(log n) insertion time, at least), or maintaining sorted order, or anything like that. If it was just these, they could easily be handled with a data structure on top of the underlying elements, and the elements themselves could be stored in an array. It also doesn't even have anything to do with guarantees about *iterator* invalidation, since iterators are abstract.

No, the only thing holding you back is the reference invalidation requirement.